# simple (possibly) PHP problems

Tags: php, image, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to achieve a couple of things with PHP, but as a relative novice I'm slightly confused.

I have some custom fields to which I want to:

1. Add an icon to the side of it if it's true (e.g a little phone next to the number)
2. Make sure any hyperlinks don't appear in their custom field form, but rather as anchor text e.g. www.site.com becomes hyperlinked text 'Website'.

So far for 1. I have something like this:

```
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_phone', true );
if( $value == 'True' ) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png">';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_phone', true );
?>
```

So far for 2. which combines both problems I have something like this:

```
<?php $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_wesbite', true );
    if ($ecpt_phone, true) {
?>
<h4>
  '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png">'
  <a href="'ecpt_website'">Visit Website</a>
</h4>
<?php } else { ?>

    { echo 'display:none;'; }

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code above isn't working so I've gone wrong somewhere

Comment: What do you mean by **Isn't working** ? What errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry - it display nothing at all yet the custom fields are populated

Comment: What does your `get_post_meta` function looks like? I guess there is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mess:

- [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) returns the value, so comparing it to the string `'True'` in your first example does not make any sense;
- In your second example you are mixing css and html;
- In your second example you have `'` characters all over the place where you should not have them, for example `'<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.png">'`;
- In your second example you are not using the meta value at all in the html output, it should be something like `<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_wesbite', true ); ?>">Visit Website</a>`.

No offence, but you really should read up on basic html, css and php.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - sorry as i say I am a bit new.

On the final bit that Hyperlink does work but directs to the site it's deployed on rather than the ecpt_website field data